# how to respond to an event on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

I have implemented a rabbitMQ listener, which essentially just sits in a loop waiting for messages to arrive. When the message arrives I wish to fire an event and run some code.

However I don't always seem to receive this event, and I am wondering if this is because I am running the queue polling part of the code on a different thread.

It does seem to work initially though, so it is possible that the threading is not the problem. Can anyone give me an opinion on this?

**QueueListener:**

```
 public void CreateQueueListener<T>() where T : IPubSubEvent
    {            

        var mqServer = new RabbitMqServer(m_RabbitMqAddress);
        var mqClient = (RabbitMqQueueClient)mqServer.MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient();

        var channel = mqClient.Channel;
        string queueName = mqClient.GetTempQueueName();


        channel.QueueBind(queueName, m_EventExchange, routingKey: QueueNames<T>.In);

        var consumer = new RabbitMqBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                BasicGetResult basicGetResult;
                try
                {
                    basicGetResult = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                var message = basicGetResult.ToMessage<T>();
                PublishEvent?.Invoke(this, new PubSubEventArgs { EventData = message.GetBody().EventName });                    
            }
        });
    }
```

**Consuming Class**

```
public class MyClass
{
 public MyClass(IEventClient eventClient)
    {
        eventClient.CreateQueueListener<AuthoriseEvent>();
        eventClient.PublishEvent += OnPublishEvent;
    }

    private async void OnPublishEvent(object sender, PubSubEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EventData == "AuthoriseEvent")
            //dostuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am running the queue polling part of the code on a different thread

As far as I know, this isn't supported by the .NET client.